How to right click mouse without focusing an item underneath cursor in File Explorer window?
I want to achieve that even if there is an item underneath cursor.

I'll be surprised if there is a means. Right-click typically generates a context menu, the context of which is that under the cursor/mouse pointer. To do otherwise is contradictory.

Shift+F10 is the keyboard command.  I can't remember if it targets the cursor, but I don't think it does.  If nothing's selected, it shows in the window, top-left.
